# How to copy each line 19 times, incrementing two different numbers by 180?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, gvim, text-generation, enumerate

I had asked a similar question previously ([How to copy each line 11 times, incrementing the last "1" in each line from 2-12](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/how-to-copy-each-line-11-times-incrementing-the-last-1-in-each-line-from-2-12)). I wasn't sure if I should ask this follow-up question in that same thread or not, but I think it might have been confusing to do that, so I'll ask a new question instead.

I would like to take a line that looks like*:

```
...?start=0&end=180&...
```

and copy it 19 times such that each of the two numbers is incremented by 180, so it would look like:

```
...?start=0&end=180&...
...?start=180&end=360&...
...?start=360&end=540&...
...
...?start=3420&end=3600&...
```

How can I do that (preferably with a one-line command, but a macro is fine too)?

Thank you all very much.

*The `...` represents other text in the line, before and after that particular segment. (Also, in case it's relevant, I'll note that the one `?` character and the two `&` characters shown in that segment of the line are the only occurrences of those characters in the entire line.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record a macro, carry out your instructions, close the macro, then run it.

In your case you may start with the cursor at the beginning of the line to copy.
Press `qa` to start recording macro 'a' (you can pick any letter, but beware these are the same registers as the copy-paste registers).
Then carry out your actions: copy the line `yy`, paste it `p`, find a sure fire way to place your cursor in the right location, maybe `/?`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, add 180 `180`<kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> (or whatever shortcut is defined for you to add a number), move the cursor, add again, then move the cursor to the beginning of the current line (not necessary in this particular case but good practice), finally, close the recording with `q`.

Now run the macro once or 18 times `@a` / `18@a`.

---

**EDIT**: alternative answer, using the answer to your similar question:

```
:%s/\(.*start=\)\([0-9]\+\)\(.*end=\)\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/\=join(map(range(1, 20), 'submatch(1) . (submatch(2) + (v:val-1) * 180) . submatch(3) . (submatch(4) + (v:val-1) * 180) . submatch(5)'), "\n")/
```

Comment: I used `/=`, Enter, then `l` to get the cursor to the right location; then several `l`'s to do it the second time. I was having the problem that `<C-a>` was selecting all text instead of incrementing. I recalled having that problem before - I had forgotten what I had done before, but I did a bit of searching and recalled that I had followed some instructions on another board and set the `+` sign to be increment with `nnoremap <kPlus> <C-a>` and set the `-` sign to be decrement with `nnoremap <kMinus> <C-x>`), so I used `+` instead of `<C-a>`. Anyway, it worked! Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome + alternative solution in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Your alternate solution - the one-line command that I was looking for - works as well. Great work! Thanks again.